# Merge datasets in R

Tags: r, join, merge, dataset

I would appreciate your help with this. I am trying to merge two datasets. Dataset1 has 12 observations (one observation for every month of the year). Dataset2 has 14 observations. The key variable is Month. The 2 additional observations in Dataset2 correspond to 2 additional rows in June. So, in the merged dataset I get three rows for June. The problem is that the merged dataset is replicating the information in Dataset1 to the two additional rows. I need those two additional rows to be NAs (as shown in the picture). I have tried using the merge and join functions and both replicate the data. Could you please show me how to solve this?

[image: This is how the merge data should look]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we cannot copy/paste the data into R. Most merging questions options are addressed already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is specifically and fundamentally opposite of what join/merge operations are supposed to to, so it won't happen within `merge(...)`. However, you can make it happen after the fact.

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Key = c("January", "June"), Seller1 = c(500, 1000))
dat2 <- data.frame(Key = c("January", "June", "June", "June"), Seller2 = c(800, 2000, 1000, 2000))

merged <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "Key", all = TRUE)
merged[,names(dat1)]
#       Key Seller1
# 1 January     500
# 2    June    1000
# 3    June    1000
# 4    June    1000
duplicated(merged[,names(dat1)])
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
merged[duplicated(merged[,names(dat1)]), "Seller1"] <- NA
merged
#       Key Seller1 Seller2
# 1 January     500     800
# 2    June    1000    2000
# 3    June      NA    1000
# 4    June      NA    2000
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = 'Key') %>%
          mutate(Seller1 = replace(Seller1, duplciated(Seller1), NA))
```